# Storing the specific value that matches when an array is being searched in str_replace()

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

The function `str_replace()` accepts an array as its first parameter, but I don't see any way to store the string for use in the second parameter where the found text is replaced. For instance, if I want to format around the string with brackets or quotation marks.

Here's an example. Say I was looking to insert quotation marks around the words in $array when they're spit back out or change the case of the word to from all lowercase to the case set in $array:

```
$array = array('Over','Dog','Quick');

$string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

$string = explode(" ",$string);

foreach ($string as $word) {

    echo str_replace($array, "???", $word);

    echo " ";

}
```

That will return `The ??? brown fox jumps ??? the lazy ???`. I realize this might be a job for regex, but I haven't been able to figure out how to get it to handle both formatting and replacing. I feel like I'm missing something here, but nothing I google even touches this subject.

Comment: This is what preg_replace is for: http://uk.php.net/preg_replace

Comment: Look into [`preg_replace_callback`](http://us.php.net/preg_replace_callback). With it, you can specify a function which will be used to transform the matched value into a wanted replacement. (Also, you can pass an array as the first argument to `str_replace`/`preg_replace`, and each element in that array will be replaced.)

Comment: Use an array as the second argument too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
$array = array('Over', 'Dog', 'Quick');

$string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

echo str_ireplace($array, $array, $string);
```

See it here in action: http://viper-7.com/q7n7uw

---

So, for example, if you want to put quotation marks around the string, use this:

```
$array = array('Over', 'Dog', 'Quick');
$replacements = array();
foreach($array as $item) $replacements[] = '"' . $item . '"';

$string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

echo str_ireplace($array, $replacements, $string);
```

See here: http://viper-7.com/2afgL5

---

In reality though, this is a job for `preg_replace`:

```
$search = array('Over','Dog','Quick');

foreach($search as &$item) $item = '~\b(' . $item . ')\b~i';

$string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

echo preg_replace($search, '"$1"', $string);
```

See here: http://viper-7.com/nAlqzX

Comment: Thanks. I didn't want to get into the preg functions